# Expo ImagePicker not working properly in android

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-image-picker

Asked permission in `componentDidMount`

```
async componentDidMount() {
  await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
  await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
}
```

Photo picker function

```
_takePhoto = async () => {
  let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
     allowsEditing: true,
     aspect: [4, 3]
   });

  this._handleImagePicked(pickerResult);
 };
```

Render area

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._takePhoto}>
  <Text> Upload Image </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Version

```
Expo SDK : "^31.0.2"
Tested android version: 7.1
```

Permission in app

```
"READ_PHONE_STATE",
"CAMERA",
"READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE",
"WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE",
"READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
"WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

**When I build the apk and run it in device I camera is not opening when I click on the button. Inside expo its working fine.**